# odd numpy behaviour, what's happening here?

Tags: python, numpy

I was having trouble using numpy.average, it hit an error every time until I converted the inputs to numpy.float64s. I had a look at the source and it's because of the following behaviour, what's the reason for the difference?

```
>>> f, f32 = numpy.float(1.0), numpy.float32(1.0)

>>> (f == 1.0).any()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#80>", line 1, in <module>
    (f == 1.0).any()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
>>> (f32 == 1.0).any()
True
```

Comment: `numpy.float` is just an alias for the builtin python `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because a `numpy.float32` object doesn't return a `bool` object upon comparison with `__eq__`, but a `numpy.bool_` one.

```
>>> type((f == 1.0))
<type 'bool'>
>>> type((f32 == 1.0))
<type 'numpy.bool_'>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> type(numpy.float32(1.0))
<type 'numpy.float32'>
>>> type(numpy.float(1.0))
<type 'float'>
>>> type(numpy.float32(1.0) == 1.0)
<type 'numpy.bool_'>
>>> type(numpy.float(1.0) == 1.0)
<type 'bool'>
```

The `numpy.float32` and `numpy.bool_` are used to not only store scalar but also vector:

```
>>> numpy.float32([1.0, 2.0])
array([ 1.,  2.], dtype=float32)
>>> numpy.float32([1.0, 2.0]) == 1.0
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

So there is an `any()` function in `numpy.bool_` to check whether any of the items is True.

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally need to use expressions like `numpy.float(1.0)`.

The most common, basic operation in `numpy` is to make an array.

```
f = np.array([1.0, 1.23])
mf = f.mean()  # or
mf = np.mean(f)
```

or with integers

```
f = np.array([1, 3, 5, 3, 5])
f==3
(f==3).any()
```

Note I am using integers with `==` test.  `==` test is not a good idea when using floats.

I could go further and specify the `dtype`:

```
 f = np.arange(5, dtype=int)
 f = np.ones((3,4), dtype=float)
```

Individual items of these arrays will be of type `np.float`, `np.int`, etc.  There's rarely a need to create one directly `np.float(1.23)`. Specify the `dtype` when creating an array, but otherwise let `numpy` take care of those details.